# Repeated merge of VSS branch->trunk when trunk version unchanged

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

Merging whole projects is a pain in VSS as the IDE only wants to let you do individual files. I have a situation where we created a new project (in both the VSS and VC++ sense) in a branch, and I then merged/copied this into trunk. All active development is still going on in the branch, the trunk version has no independent changes and this is likely to continue for some time as changes are made in the branch and then merged into trunk.

I wodnered if the easiest solution is simply to delete the trunk version of the project and re-copy the branch version each time, since it avoids the need to do any fiddly stuff and makes sure the trunk version is exactly the same as the branch at time of copying.

Does that seem reasonable or does it introduce problems I hadn't foreseen?

Comment: *does it introduce problems I hadn't foreseen?* [It introduces the problem that you'll still be using SourceSafe afterwards](https://code.google.com/p/vss2git/).

Comment: That's not unforeseen :) And git is the last VCS I'd want to change to (migration to TFS is already planned though SVN would be my preference). But it's a bit silly/naive for developers to suggest other developers can just change their entire company toolset.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this: check out the trunk and use **Reconcile All** in Project Difference dialog box to reconcile the changes in the branch. [Here](http://www.kevingao.net/version-control/sourcesafe/project-diff.html) is an article on VSS Project Diff.